# The same SOQL query returns different results from Apex code which was called from LWC

Tags: apex, soql, permission-sets

I need to get tab visibility for Permission Set. I have tabs for 2 objects:Account and Account__c. I use this SOQl request:

```
SELECT Id,Name,Visibility,ParentId FROM PermissionSetTabSetting WHERE (ParentId IN ('0PS5g000005r8bWGAQ')) AND (Name IN ('standard-Account','Account__c'))  ORDER BY Id ASC NULLS FIRST  LIMIT 2000
```

0PS5g000005r8bWGAQ - Permission Set Id
standard-Account,Account__c - tab Names from TabDefinition.

When i use this query in anonymous, sf inspector or query editor it returns required data :
[image]

BUT !!!
When i use this query in my Apex code(i hardcoded it) it returns me null.

I found out that in my transaction Name of standard tab is replaced from 'standard-Account' to 'Account'.

And Name of custom tab is replaced from  'Account__c ' to '01r5g000000EJou'. It's CustomTadDefinition id.

So
If i replace my SOQl query In Apex class like that:

```
 SELECT Id,Name,Visibility,ParentId FROM PermissionSetTabSetting WHERE (ParentId IN ('0PS5g000005r8bWGAQ')) AND (Name IN ('Account','01r5g000000EJou'))  ORDER BY Id ASC NULLS FIRST  LIMIT 2000
```

i'll get all needed info.

But to get CustomTadDefinition id , i need to use Tolling API for each custom tab.

**This apex method is triggered from LWC.
When i call this method from anonymous it works fine.**

**It's the same user, i checked it.**
**I use without sharing classes.**

I don't understand why i get different result.

Comment: The most common reason is that you have actually used different users in the two cases and there are sharing rules in use.

Comment: It's the same user, i checked it.
I use without sharing classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some strange reason in `LWC`, `Name` field from `PermissionSetTabSetting` returns either standard object name or custom tab id, while in `Classic`, it returns the tab name.

Workaround here is to use `Tooling API` with `Classic Session Id`.

Create Visualforce Page 'Api'.

```
<apex:page controller="ApiCont" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    {!sid}
</apex:page>
```

Create Apex Controller ApiCont.

```
public with sharing class ApiCont {
    public static String SEPAR = '[|]';
    public String sid{ get{ return SEPAR + UserInfo.getSessionId() + SEPAR ;} set;}
}
```

Create Apex class ApiService.

```
public with sharing class ApiService{
    @testVisible static String sid;
    public static String getClassicSessionId() {
        if (sid == null) {
            sid = new PageReference(
                '/apex/Api'
            ).getContent().toString().substringBetween(ApiCont.SEPAR, ApiCont.SEPAR);
        }
        return sid;
    }
}
```

Create Apex class ToolingApi.

```
public with sharing class ToolingApi {
    static String restGet(String endPoint, String method, String sid) {
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest hr = new HttpRequest();
        hr.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sid);
        hr.setTimeout(60000);
        hr.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        hr.setMethod(method);
        HttpResponse r = h.send(hr);
        return r.getBody();
    }
    public static String query(String query) {
        String baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
        return restGet( baseURL + '/services/data/v52.0/tooling/query?q='+ (query.replace(' ', '+')), 'GET', ApiService.getClassicSessionId() );
    }
}
```

Now if you run it as Tooling Api query, it will return correct results even in LWC:

```
String body = ToolingApi.query('SELECT Name, ParentId, Visibility FROM PermissionSetTabSetting WHERE ParentId IN (\'' + String.join(parentIds, '\',\'') + '\')');
        
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error,  'body: ' + body);
```

Wherever you used to have query

```
SELECT Name, ParentId, Visibility
FROM PermissionSetTabSetting
WHERE ParentId IN: parentIds
```

use instead

```
Map<String, Object> dataMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(body);  
(List<PermissionSetTabSetting>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(dataMap.get('records')), List<PermissionSetTabSetting>.class )
```